Visual Studio 2022 DEP0700 ERROR - Registration of the app failed due to missing framework
I'm learning .NET MAUI for the first time, and currently learning XAML using Microsoft's training exercise. The only problem is when I try to deploy this app, I get this error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF3] Windows cannot install package 0A39EF64-0606-4941-8C45-EAB3CF9DE53D_1.0.0.1_x64__9zz4h110yvjzm because this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x64 processor architecture and minimum version 14.0.24217.0, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" currently installed are: {}  Notes

I installed VCLibs.VCRuntime via Nuget but it looks like it's referring to a different package. My Target .NET Runtime is net 8.0, and on Windows Server 2019.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Seems like the error is clear. Install the required framework.

According to your error log, you can try to remove the package dependency:Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 in the platform file: Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest as a temporarily fix.
For more details, you can refer to this similar issue:Error DEP0700
#7299
